# How to use scroll lock as a keyboard shortcut [18.04/GNOME]?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'd like to use the scroll lock key as a keyboard shortcut for `Volume Down` in Ubuntu 18.04. This worked fine in 14.04 but it seems GNOME won't recognize the key anymore.

I *do not* want to use the scroll bar as a mod key. I tried setting it as `Mod 3` as some answers suggest and that doesn't work either.

Comment: can you share a pic of your keyboard.. is scroll lock button a seperate button or sharing with other key also?

Comment: This is the keyboard: http://www.coolermaster.com/peripheral/keyboards/masterkeys-l-with-superior-pbt-keycaps/

Comment: Scroll lock is a separate button

Comment: Ok, did you try to get the code for this button with `xev` command?

Comment: I tried it on my toshiba laptop.. it worked as expected.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with a separate Scroll Lock key. It's being detected as a valid keypress when running xev but when using the GNOME Keyboard shortcut menu and pressing Scroll Lock as an option for a key, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

**Answer**: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down "['Scroll_Lock']"`

**Explaining to myself (for future reference)**:

Ubuntu comes with *xev*, that capture input from keyboard and mouse.
Open *xev* and press scroll lock, there you can see what is the command associated with the key

[image]

"Scroll_Lock" is the string that represents the key scroll lock.

---

**Observation**:
Some popular media keys can be found inside `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml`

For example, there you will find that **XF86Calculator** is the media key that open the calculator and **XF86AudioPause** is the media key to pause. You could make this keys do another command or action, for example:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down "['XF86AudioPause']"`

[image]

---

**Custom keybindings:**
Very annoying... I recommend you to create a custom keybinding empty and add the key using the terminal.
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding 'Scroll_Lock'`

**custom0** is the first custom keybinding
**custom1** is the second custom keybiding
**custom2** is the third custom keybinding...

---

**References**:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings
https://techwiser.com/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-ubuntu/